# C++ (Visual Studio) Как подключить и использовать библиотеку с файлами *.dll, *dll.a, *.a?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, curl, libcurl

Windows 10. Visual Studio 2022. С++

Я пытаюсь подключить [эту библиотеку (curl-impersonate-win)](https://github.com/depler/curl-impersonate-win/releases). В архиве есть 3 файла:

- libcurl.dll
- libcurldll.a
- libcurl.a

Я никак не пойму зачем нужны файлы *.a и как мне вообще подключать и использовать в Visual Studio C++. Обычно для подключения нужны файлы *.lib, *.dll и *.h, но в данном случае их нет. Адекватных примеров подключения без *.lib и *.h файлов я не нашел. Документация Microsoft про явное и неявное подключение только сбивает меня с толку.

Comment: Поскать не пробовали? curl.h - https://github.com/tpruvot/ccminer/blob/windows/compat/curl-for-windows/curl/include/curl/curl.h  Делать .LIB - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file

Comment: Файлы .a предназначены для gcc (mingw). Файлы .h нужны, возможно они остались в исходниках